# How to deploy perfectly Laravel Project with ReactJS to the server

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have project combination of Laravel and ReactJS but i got problem deploying it to our server almost 2 weeks still don't know why i can't access it.
when i try to access the browser.

> This site can’t be reached

Step that i do before I deploy the project.

1. NPM Install
2. npm run production
3. zip the files to my computer and paste to the server

No error found when i view the error.log in our server.

Why it happen when i type my link

Example. 
**www.thisisexamplewebsite.ca
The .ca domain turns to cauwsta**

I hope someone could help me and to solved my problem.

[image: Error]